# Can positively check S3 bucket existence but won't be able to list its objects

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building my S3 buckets like nested directories in order to store files by some criteria, and the first thing that I noticed is that, for example, take into account that **sample** only stores those **test=xxx** keys which are the ones that in final instance store files.

```
s3Client.doesBucketExistV2("one/two/sample") // true
s3Client.doesBucketExistV2("one/two/sample/test=123") // false
```

Both exist and **test=xxx** contains files but they weren't created manually by me in AWS, but by a program.

`Why test=xxx doesn't return`true`instead of`false`?`

And my second doubt is when trying to list objects for a given bucket...

```
s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
   .withBucketName("one/")
   .withPrefix("two/")
   .withPrefix("sample/")) // The specified key does not exist. [404]
```

`Why can't I list the objects of a given bucket that exists?`

Comment: You are not using these methods correctly. `doesBucketExistV2()` expects a *bucket*.  `"one/two/sample"` is not a valid bucket name -- buckets can't have `/` in the name -- so, in fact, the value that is wrong is the one that returns `true`.  There should also not be a `/` in the argument to `.withBucketName()`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but then how is it possible to check existence in nested buckets? Should I access parent one before in any way?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "nested bucket" -- buckets can't be inside other buckets, because the *bucket* is the top level container, and your bucket's name must be a bucket name that no other S3 account is using, because bucket names are a global namespace.  Anything inside a bucket is an *object* which has a unique *key [name]* within that bucket.  Multiple objects may share a *common [key] prefix*, separated by a *delimiter* (typically `/`) and it sounds like that's what you are referring to.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot exactly, sorry for that, completely mistaken with the concept of bucket. Now that I know that I must refer to them as objects, the issue goes beyond S3 itself I think right into Apache Spark, which is the one generating those keys together a `fileName_$folder$`, and whereas that `$folder$` file is being recognized, the `fileName/` key itself doesn't seem to exist for the `doesObjectExist` method, even if its there and more objects include that prefix.

Comment: `ListObjectsRequest(...).withBucketName("example-bucket").withPrefix("one/two/sample/")`  would find objects in the *bucket* `example-bucket` with *object keys* like `one/two/sample/funny-cat.png` and `one/two/sample/serious-cat.png`.

Comment: Objects like `my-folder/` or `my-folder_$folder$` are really confusing to neophytes.  They don't have any meaning to S3 itself.  Spark makes those garbage `$` objects and the S3 console creates 0-byte objects ending in `/` strictly for navigational convenience if you create a "folder" in the console, but S3 itself has no use for, and imputes no meaning to, either of these things.  They have no meaning to S3, and you should assume they aren't going to be there... yet you also need to ignore them in your code if you do encounter them.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks a lot for the help regarding that, would you please put all that in an answer so I can accept it? Really complete and helpful :)

Comment: Yes, within a few hours from now.

Answer (score 1):

the second .withPrefix("sample/") overrides .withPrefix("two/"). It does not concatenate the strings.

The bucketname, prefix and key are separate things. So doesBucketExistV2() proofs in the last case on a key.

```
Your bucketname is: one
Your prefix is: /two/
or Another prefix is: /two/sample/
with the key: "test=xxx"


s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
   .withBucketName("one")
   .withPrefix("/two/sample/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
list_of_files = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=your-bucket)['Contents']
```